How to create non-collapsable heading in Microsoft Word
So in order to get my text to not collapse under heading 2, but collapsed under heading 1, I had to shift around headings and make the first phrase of the text into its own heading (hopefully I've explained that right). The issue is the little triangle thing beside my text now is REALLY upsetting me. And it's in the way too.
Is there a way to make a non-collapsible heading? So that way it still affects the outline level, but the triangle isn't there?
It's not letting me post images here, but I have the images (For clarity) in a Reddit post, so here's the link to that: https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftWord/comments/1btaovu/how_to_make_a_heading_noncollapsible/

I think that Word implements collapse/expand only for paragraphs which have a numbered Level, so you could try creating a new paragraph header without a level number.

Brief response: If you want an outline level you are stuck with collapse/expand. See my page on Outlining In Word: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm
If you can work in Word 2010 or 2007 you will not have the expand/collapse feature - @harrymc In Word, an Outline level is a numbered level, even if there is no numbering attached.

@CharlesKenyon: Before writing my above comment, I have tried storing a document in "Word 97-2003 Document" format, which was not enough. Apparently one would need the real old software itself, which is normally out of the question.

@Hanna:  According to the comment by Charles Kenyon the paragraph style to use must not be an outline in order not to be collapsible. Another idea is to insert a section break before the text that shouldn't be collapsible and ensure no heading styles are applied to text within the new section.
